# what is the shortcut key to accept ms teams call / keyboard shortcut?

Tags: microsoft-teams

is there a shortcut key to join when someone starts an ms teams meeting and i get the notification to either join or (send)message? [this is the first notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toHNH.png)

after i join, i get another screen on which i can turn on/off video and audio and a join-button to actually join the meeting. is there a shortcut key on this screen, to join ?

i already tried Ctrl+Shift+S and Ctrl+Shift+A. this doesn't work.

Comment: Currently teams doesn't have any short-cut key to join the call. Could you please raise a [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently teams doesn't have any short-cut key to join the call. Could you please raise a [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)?